# Reactions of acidified substances

Tags: acid-base

**Case study: acidified potassium manganate(VII)**

Does "acidified" suggest that the substance contains $\ce{H+}$ions?
If so, will acidified $\ce{KMnO4}$ react with a base, such as ammonia?

Comment: Yes it will react, but it is the $\ce{H+}$ that is reacting, not the $\ce{KMnO4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permanganates, like KMnO4 are powerful oxidizers, but their redox potential and thus reactions are pH dependent. Lowering the pH by adding an acid increases the oxidizing power of permanganates.

Acidified KMnO4 most likely means a solution of KMnO4, with some sulfuric acid added. Since the solution is acidic it will react with bases like ammonia, but that is not the intended reaction of such a solution. It is used to oxidize a wide range of organic and inorganic chemicals, for example toluene to benzoic acid.